# Why was Producer Alex fired from Stack Exchange podcast

Tags: discussion, podcast

In the last couple of podcasts, there were several references to Producer Alex being fired.

What was the reason for that? (He's still in SE and even on the podcast, so I assume it's some sort of in-joke).

Comment: Maybe he was literally set on fire? ;)

Comment: He denied my request for doing a full episode on bacon, and bacon only.

Comment: Psh, that's nothing. I get fired every single day, that's why I was promoted to CPO (chief pun officer).

Comment: @Jin That should have gotten him fired *and* deported.

Comment: @Jin While bacon is a fantastic product, I think Americans have gone crazy when I hear about [bacon milkshakes](http://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/bacon-milkshakes/d7d44522-b8a2-4ddc-a73b-cc906092d690). Those milkshakes will not bring all the girls to the yard.

Comment: @Jin - timely... today's new Freakonomics podcast discussed bacon extensively. Perhaps their producer should replace Alex.

Answer (score 6):

It's *exactly* what you think it is.

Comment: So he got fired, then re-hired as a temp with no benefits, crazy hours, and has to hand-roll sushi for Taco Saturdays and Sundays? That's disgusting. The Division of Labor Standards will be hearing about this.

Comment: @Pëkka, I went out of my way *not* to spell it out and embarrass him, given that it was so obvious, anyway. Oh well; can't unring the bell, I suppose.

Comment: @Pëkka Just stop it. All you're really annoyed about is that you weren't able to pick him up yourself for your genuine handbag business.

Comment: @Bart you don't know what Alex does during his 4 spare hours every day.

Comment: @Pëkka - he gets 4 spare hours a day? What kind of sweatshop are you running?

Comment: @Oded he works for me during the 4 spare hours he has from temping at SE and feeding Taco.

Comment: Phew, @Pëkka - for a while there I thought he had time to sleep.

Comment: While I appreciate the Microsoft Support style pithiness and correctness of the answer, some detail of WHAT the point of the joke was would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Oded pfft. That's such a socialist concept.

Comment: @dvk, I know I should usually assume that,  "if you have to explain the joke... it's not much of a joke".  In this case, though, the joke WAS that not explaining it lets you form your own funnier suppositions. He's just sort of busy doing other big-important-VP-of-Operations type things, so we brought Abby in to help with logistics (and because she's a little more plugged in to a lot of the individual communities.  (See how that fails to be amusing by unfairly implying Alex did something awful?)

Comment: @Jaydles - perhaps I am not getting it because I am way unfamiliar with creating podcasts. My idea of what a producer does is basically pushing a "record" button and sitting around while podcast runs telling people what to talk about.

Comment: @stilly.stack, thanks... I think?  As to your question, it depends on the week, but generally speaking:   I'm usually on uppers, David's on downers, and Joel's particular brand of genius is the kind that comes with a little bit of crazy.

Comment: @user0000000 The standard way to request a new feature is to  post a *feature-request*...

Comment: @user0000000, based on your username, you don't appear to be worth responding to. :p Good points on custom sorts/filters - we're looking at a few ways to let active users try something like that in the months ahead...